# Setting up the environment for django development and deployment(nginx/gunicorn/git/south/fabric)

Tags: django, git, deployment

Let's imagine I have nginx+gunicorn set up and running already. How do I set up git for deployment from local testing to remote production server?

I need instructions like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853194/best-solutions-to-deploy-from-git-to-production/3853277#3853277), but a bit more detailed and with some possible advice about using this with gunicron and nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are..https://github.com/jacobian/django-deployment-workshop